# INSERT WITH SELECT query giving me syntax error?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cordova

can anyone let me know what m i doing wrong here .....
  here is my query and getting syntax error "near SELECT" when trying to run query in sqlite database manager

```
INSERT INTO proposal_products(proposal_id,date_created,date_modified,quantity,installation_position,notes,proposal_location_id,parent_id,prompt,cost_price,sale_price,service_price,labour_hours,maint_hours,comm_hours,adj_cost_price,adj_sale_price,adj_service_price,adj_labour_hours,adj_maint_hours,adj_comm_hours,is_adjusted,adj_unit_price,discipline_products_id)VALUES('1000000','27-02-2013','27-02-2013',3,'dfdf','dsdsd',6,58,'hghfg',21,22,22,48,45,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,SELECT id FROM discipline_products WHERE product_id = SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = 'STDD')
```

here is the snap shot of error
[image]

Comment: Try adding parentheses, e.g. `...,0,1,0,(SELECT id FROM discipline_products WHERE product_id = (SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = 'STDD'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO proposal_products(proposal_id,date_created,date_modified,quantity,installation_position,notes,proposal_location_id,parent_id,prompt,cost_price,sale_price,service_price,labour_hours,maint_hours,comm_hours,adj_cost_price,adj_sale_price,adj_service_price,adj_labour_hours,adj_maint_hours,adj_comm_hours,is_adjusted,adj_unit_price,discipline_products_id)
SELECT '1000000','27-02-2013','27-02-2013',3,'dfdf','dsdsd',6,58,'hghfg',21,22,22,48,45,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, id 
FROM discipline_products 
WHERE product_id = (SELECT id FROM products WHERE c4w_code = 'STDD')
```

Comment: BUT IF i need to get values dynamically instead of providing constant values right now then how will i write?

Comment: Than You have to use variables instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO proposal_products 
(
    proposal_id,
    date_created,
    date_modified,
    quantity,
    installation_position,
    notes,
    proposal_location_id,
    parent_id,
    prompt,
    cost_price,
    sale_price,
    service_price,
    labour_hours,
    maint_hours,
    comm_hours,
    adj_cost_price,
    adj_sale_price,
    adj_service_price,
    adj_labour_hours,
    adj_maint_hours,
    adj_comm_hours,
    is_adjusted,
    adj_unit_price,
    discipline_products_id
)
VALUES( '1000000',
        '27-02-2013',
        '27-02-2013',
        3,
        'dfdf',
        'dsdsd',
        6,
        58,
        'hghfg',
        21,
        22,
        22,
        48,
        45,
        45,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
       ( SELECT id FROM discipline_products WHERE product_id = (SELECT id 
                                                                 FROM products
                                                                WHERE c4w_code = 'STDD')
        ))
```